how to insert data from the old database into the new database in laravel
how to enter data from an old database into a new database where tables have been added and several existing tables have columns added in laravel. Use Laragon as a localhost web server
I haven't tried it because I haven't found a way

Why not just migrate the existing database to the new datastructure using migrations?

learn about from this tutorial
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp
Here is your question answer how you can copy from one to another
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11691565/25571574,
